# convert string into 2D-array format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

I'm getting string from database and i need to convert it in the format below:

```
var locations = [
  ["LOCATION_1", 11.8166, 122.0942],
  ["LOCATION_2", 11.9804, 121.9189],
  ["LOCATION_3", 10.7202, 122.5621],
  ["LOCATION_4", 11.3889, 122.6277],
  ["LOCATION_5", 10.5929, 122.6325]
];
```

my code below

```
                   var array = ''
                   var arrayprev= ''
                   for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        array = '['+obj[i].Location + '"' + ',' + obj[i].x + ',' + obj[i].y + '],|'
                        if (arrayprev == "") {
                            arrayprev = array;
                        }
                        else {
                            arrayprev = arrayprev + array;
                        }
                    }
                   locations = arrayprev.split("|")
```

i'm getting only chracters when passing in code below

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], { icon: iconColor(color) })
            // PoPup result will be displayed here
          .bindPopup(locations[i][0])
            //here tool tip will be used to display the label text
          .bindTooltip(locations[i][0],
            {
                permanent: true, 
                direction: 'right'
             }
            )
          .addTo(map);
```

hardcoded location array is working fine but when I use my loop I'm not getting the correct data Please help

Comment: can you add an input string example?

Comment: from this line i'm taking data ```array = '['+obj[i].Location + '"' + ',' + obj[i].x + ',' + obj[i].y + '],|'```

Comment: what is the initial string, which you want to convert to an array is the question.

Comment: you have variables called array, which are actually strings. then you build one big string and split it again to have an array. it all seems quite confusing

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that you don't have a string as an input but an array of object

you can use `map` to trasform that array in the shape you want

like this

```
const obj = [{
  Location: "LOCATION_1",
  x:  11.8166,
  y: 122.0942
},{
  Location: "LOCATION_2",
  x:  11.8166,
  y: 122.0942
},{
  Location: "LOCATION_3",
  x:  11.8166,
  y: 122.0942
},
]

const locations = obj.map(({Location, x, y}) => [Location, x, y])
```

or you can use that array of object to populate your map

like this

```
obj.forEach(({Location, x, y}) => {
  marker = new L.marker([x, y], { icon: iconColor(color) })
            // PoPup result will be displayed here
          .bindPopup(Location)
            //here tool tip will be used to display the label text
          .bindTooltip(Location,
            {
                permanent: true, 
                direction: 'right'
             }
            )
          .addTo(map);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code, it looks like you just want to convert an object into an array containing arrays. I don't see the reason working with string here.

```
var result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    return [obj[key].Location, obj[key].x, obj[key].y]
})
```